# Losing wired connection on ubuntu several times a day (segfault)

Tags: uefi, ethernet, segmentation-fault

Several times a day I lose wired network connection. It is restored after a while.

Last time it happened, I looked at `dmesg` and found this:

```
CHTTPClientThre[12511]: segfault at ee931b6e ip 00000000ee931b6e sp 00000000e10fe010 error 14 in #23 (deleted)[eefe0000+20000]
```

I am using:

**OS:**

```
Linux clu 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**BIOS:**

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS

BIOS
```

**NETWORK CARD:**

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

**MOTHERBOARD:**

```
Manufacturer: MSI
Product Name: Z97-G45 GAMING (MS-7821)
```

Could this have something to do with not installing UEFI mode? How can I troubleshoot this further? Thanks!

Comment: A segfault has mostly two possible causes: software bugs and faulty hardware (usually the RAM). You can test for the second one with [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/).